# Serving local files if user is offline

Tags: javascript, html, css, offline, docsify

I was wondering is there a better way to serve a user with locally hosted assets if they are detected to be offline.

They wouldn't actually be offline, but due to corporate proxies sometimes the links to sites are blocked or just denied.

I have about 10 assets delivered via CDN, but it seems bad practice to write it as so:

```html
<script>
var isOnline = window.navigator.onLine;

if( isOnline ) {
    document.write('<script src="http://cdn.site.ltd/file1.js"></script>');
    document.write('<script src="http://cdn.site.ltd/file2.js"></script>');
    document.write('<script src="http://cdn.site.ltd/file3.js"></script>');
   document.write('<link href="http://cdn.site.ltd/file.css"></link>');
} else {
   document.write('<script src="../file1.js"></script>');
   document.write('<script src="../file2.js"></script>');
   document.write('<script src="../file3.js"></script>');
   document.write('<link href="../file.css"></link>');
}
</script>
```

I mean apart from the user having Javascript disabled (not the default) is this the wrong way about doing this?

I also [found this](https://gist.github.com/gitdagray/f310be81be217750fc9d2b233e2ae70c) but I dont know if its overkill for the situation or not?

Comment: Why are you using echo?

Comment: @epascarello language mix up! `document.write` is what I meant - i'll edit it

Comment: if the files exist on the local server and the local server can always be reached, but sometimes the cdn cannot be. Why not just always use the local server and forget about the cdn?

Comment: @CodyPace the cdn links would be the latest version, but the local would be the latest saved. its possible but was hoping for a balance or fallback

Comment: @charlietfl because it would serve a file on the local network instead of the internet

Comment: assuming the server always has access to the cdn you could load the files normally from a script tag and on page load make a request to the server to check if the file you got is the latest version (check if cdn and local file match). If differences are found you could have a popup or something alert the user that some files are out of date and a refresh is required. Not the best solution, but it wouldn't matter if they could reach the cdn client side this way because the files would be getting updated on the server side

Answer (score -1):

This would be the ideal use case for a ServiceWorker, wouldn't it?

Comment: Is this poor answer or just spam?